# Scheduled Apex Constructor is not visible

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I created a managed package and install into a production environment.

From the developer console, I tried to schedule the one of the class of the package.

```
zw.ARTaskWebServiceCalloutsScheduler m = new zw.ARTaskWebServiceCalloutsScheduler();
String sch = '30 27 15 18 8 ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('ARTaskWebServiceCalloutsScheduler', sch, m);
```

After I click execute, I got "Execute Anonymous Error":
Line: 1, Column: 42
Constructor is not visible: [zw.ARTaskWebServiceCalloutsScheduler].()

By the way, 
I am able to schedule it from the UI.

How can I fix this?

Code of the scheduled apex:

```
global class ARTaskWebServiceCalloutsScheduler implements Schedulable
{
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    ARTaskWebServiceCalloutsScheduler.action();
}
public ARTaskWebServiceCalloutsScheduler()
{

}

@future(callout=true)
static void action(){
    ARTaskWebServiceCallouts artwc=new ARTaskWebServiceCallouts();
    ARpartnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult lr = artwc.login();
    artwc.callTaskWebService(lr);
    artwc.processResult();
}
}
```

Comment: Is zw.ARTaskWebServiceCalloutsScheduler class global, with a global zero-argument constructor defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed package code is only available with the global keyword on a class, function, variable, etc outside of the class. The UI lets administrators schedule any class that can be scheduled, from any package, without regards to the public/global attribute of the code, but the compiler will refuse to compile an attempt to access a class, function, variable, etc that isn't global from outside the namespace. The developer of the managed package will need to provide a global function if they want this class to be schedulable by code.